# Starting an Existing Java project that has not been documented

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, frameworks, struts, websphere

I have only worked on projects that I started from scratch, but now I got to work on a pre-existing project(Web applicaation) with no documentation and no guidance. All the folks that worked on the project are gone, and my client wants me to start working on the project.

I need the best Steps to do this, and start running it in my IDE. 
Is there any efficient and non-time consuming method to start out? Any tools that might help?

All I got so far-->

1)Project.EAR file --> (module) one War file.  (backup exported from server)

2)Versions used--> Java1.4, Websphere app server v5.1, Sapjco Connectors.

3)jars in lib folder(Frameworks) list.

```
 acegi-security-1.0.2.jar
 activation.jar
 antlr.jar
 antlr-2.7.6.jar
 asm.jar
 aspectjweaver-1.5.2.jar
 cglib-2.1.3.jar
 chartengineapi.jar
 clickstream-1.0.2.jar
 com.ibm.icu_4.0.1.v20090415.jar
 commons-beanutils.jar
 commons-cli-1.0.jar
 commons-codec-1.3.jar
 commons-collections.jar
 commons-dbcp.jar
 commons-digester.jar
 commons-fileupload.jar
 commons-io.jar
 commons-lang.jar
 commons-logging.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.jar
 commons-pool.jar
 commons-validator.jar
 coreapi.jar
 crosstabcoreapi.jar
 dataadapterapi.jar
 dataaggregationapi.jar
 dataextraction.jar
 displaytag-1.1.jar
 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 dteapi.jar
 dwr.jar
 ehcache-1.2.3.jar
 emitterconfig.jar
 engineapi.jar
 flute.jar
 itext-1.3.3.jar
 jakarta-oro.jar
 jaxen-full.jar
 js.jar
 jstl.jar
 jta.jar
 log4j-1.2.11.jar
 mail.jar
 modelapi.jar
 modelodaapi.jar
 odadesignapi.jar
 org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0.v20080530-1600.jar
 org.eclipse.emf.common_2.5.0.v200906080927.jar
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.5.0.v200906080927.jar
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.5.0.v200906080927.jar
 org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.v200805290154.jar
 oscache-2.3.2.jar
 sapjco.jar
 saxpath.jar
 scriptapi.jar
 servletapi-2.3.jar
 sitemesh-2.2.1.jar
 spring.jar
 spring-batch-infrastructure-1.1.2.jar
 spring-mock.jar
 standard.jar
 struts.jar
 struts-el.jar
 struts-menu-2.4.2.jar
 taglibs-datetime.jar
 taglibs-mailer.jar
 taglibs-string.jar
 urlrewrite-3.0-beta.jar
 utility.jar
 velocity-1.4.jar
 velocity-tools-view-1.1.jar
```

I know starting out is always time consuming. But i need better way to start this project

NEED:--

1) What frameworks used in this project.

2) Whats the best way to start. (Clear steps please)

3) Which (open source)Server I can use as alternative to Websphere v5.

Regards.

**Edited**

Jars added (sorry i forgot to mention some jars in lib)

Comment: Best way to start is just start.

Comment: Eclipse documentation provides a very good list of steps for this: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjimpear.html

Comment: Importing project in IDE is the best way to start.

Comment: Yes I did import in eclipse but it is giving me alot of errors and not even starting. So i thought am missing something here. May be there are Some steps that i should concern before starting the project, like Configuring xml files. I need What things to check before i start running.

Comment: When you import it into eclipse ensure that you set the correct web server in the project enviornment. Most likely you have some jars missing that are bundled in the server already and eclipse doesnt know about it. Another way is to move it to a maven project. This can simplify the search for all the jars needed. Else its going one by one until you got no class not found exceptions anyway just to get it running.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I found out something so far.
framework used is "AppFuse". 
I finally fixed all libraries and running fine in Tomcat server. Now i can start Fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Write once, run anywhere" unfortunately doesn't mean you can compile the source code or start the result without errors.

The first step is probably to identify which IDE was used to develop the project with. Look for some specific files:

- `.project` and `.classpath` -> Eclipse
- `*.ipr` -> IDEA
- `pom.xml` -> Maven

Import the project using the original IDE (make sure you use the same version if you can) so you can start and compile the project without errors.

If there are no such files, curse the people who did it. If they still work at your place, get in touch with their manager and give them input for the next performance interview ("leaves project zombies behind").

If you run into big trouble doing this step: Ask colleagues for help. Web projects are all similar but there are many subtle problems to get them working, so it's much more effective to pair with someone than, say, asking here.

You can also try to locate the original team members; they *probably* haven't all left the planet. Google is your friend here and maybe someone at your company stayed in contact.

Now your questions:

> What frameworks used in this project.

Lots. Apparently, they just took whatever they needed. That said, this list looks pretty common for most web projects that go beyond "hello world."

> Whats the best way to start.

See above.

> Which (open source)Server I can use as alternative to Websphere v5.

WebSphere has a lot of .... "features" which can't be found anywhere else.

I suggest to try to get the app working with WebSphere *first* and then try [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

In order not to get insane with WebSphere's startup times, get a powerful machine with lots of RAM, install it locally and use [scripting to configure/control WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html) (at the bottom of the page are scripts for WebSphere 5).